# Función que retorne 9 dígitos

Tags: python, funciones

Necesito ayuda para crear una función que retorne 9 números aleatorios
Esto es como lo he intentado hacer, estoy seguro de que esta mal pero es para que puedan entender mi idea. Muchas gracias de antemano

```
import random

def crear_id(random):
    list = []
    for i in range(9):
        a = random.randint(0, 10)
        list.append(a)

    print(crear_id)
```

Comment: `return [random.randint(0, 10) for x in range(9)]`

Answer (score 1):

El código no está tan mal, pero tienes 4 problemas:
1- estás padando un módulo como argumento de la función, esto no es necesario ya que los import son globales.
2- No estás retornando el resultado de la función.
3- Estás sobreescribiendo una función propia de python `list()`, le puse `lista` para diferenciarla.
4- Para ejecutar la función tienes que terminar con paréntesis el llamado: `crear_id()`.

```py
import random

def crear_id():
    lista = []
    for i in range(9):
        a = random.randint(0, 10)
        lista.append(a)
    return lista

print(crear_id())
```

Ahora bien, se puede modificar esa función para que sea más dinámica, por ejemplo, que retorne la cantidad que quieras y en los límites max y min deseados:

```py
import random

def crear_id(qty, start, end):
    lista = []
    for i in range(qty):
        a = random.randint(start, end)
        lista.append(a)
    return lista

print(crear_id(3, 0, 10))
# [3, 0, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar más características de python como la *list coprehension* o el typing:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from random import randint
from typing import List

def generate_random_numbers(qty: int) -> List[int]:
    return [randint(0, 10) for random_number in range(qty)] 

print(generate_random_numbers(4))
```